# Ajax Redirect role = 'Editor' to their Dashboard after register

Tags: ajax, user-roles, editor, user-registration

How to redirect the user with role `Editor` to their respective dashboard after register?

Here is the **Ajax Script:**

`wp_localize_script('jquery_login','ajax_object',array('ajax_url'=>admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),'redirecturl' => get_dashboard_url()));`

The **Ajax Code:**

```
success: function(data){
    if(data.reg==true){
    jQuery('#reg_message').prepend('Register Successfully. Redirecting...');
    window.setTimeout(function(){
    document.location.href = ajax_object.redirecturl;
    }, 2000);
}
```

I also tried this `window.location.href = ajax_object.redirecturl;` but the url redirect to admin login page.

Comment: To make sure of the redirect URL, see the output of `redirecturl` in your source.

Comment: It shows `http://www.demo.com/wp-admin/` and redirects to login page.

Comment: Try to use my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set your address with the static method. For example:

```
wp_localize_script(
    'jquery_login',
    'ajax_object', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'redirecturl' => get_bloginfo('url') . '/user/dashboard' // Your Address
    )
);
```

Comment: Not working same output redirects to admin login page.

Comment: Clear the browser cache and try to check.

Comment: What to add in `// Your Address`, I cant figure out.

Comment: You should set a path for redirection. for e.g. `'/user/dashboard'` or `'/user/profile`'. Then make sure about this hook in your WordPress `login_redirect`

Comment: it only works if u add `function login_new_user( $user_id ) 
{
    wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, false, is_ssl() );
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'login_new_user' );`